# django giving Site errors after using django-allauth

Tags: django, django-allauth

I recently decided to add django-allauth to my application and it requires that I include 'django.contrib.sites' inside my settings.INSTALLED.APPS. 
This is causing my program to break with error `Site matching query does not exist.`
I tried creating a new site and then using that site_id in my settings and that didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. My `SITE_ID` in my settings wasn't capitalized.